# cURL returning JSON result

Tags: php, json, curl

Good evening,

I'm using cURL to send a GET request to a URL which is supplying JSON in return:

```
$material = 
function sendRequest($item1, $item2){
  $curl = curl_init('http://host.com/folder/?param1='.$item1.'&param2='.$item2);
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);  print_r($resp); //will return '1'
  return $resp;
}

$JSONArray = json_decode($material,true);
```

In the console I can see what looks to be a JSON response, but when I try to use either $material or $JSONArray, I only get the value '1'.

Why isn't JSONArray receiving the full JSON file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with different options, it seems when I add this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

It works....